# Is there a way to customize Bootstrap v5.3 files? I just need the navbar ones

Tags: bootstrap-5

I am looking to use the Bootstrap v5.3 navbar only files. I found several links to do so but for older versions. Is there a way to do that with the latest?

I tried looking at the official site but couldn't find what I needed.

https://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: You can use Sass and Webpack to package only the Bootstrap modules that you need for the menu. These pages from Bootstrap might help get you started: [Optimize](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/optimize/), [Webpack](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/getting-started/webpack/), [Sass](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/sass/), and [JavaScript](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/getting-started/javascript/).

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much!